# request reduce module stopped working once switched over to https

Tags: requestreduce

Basically we've used the below link for a number of months with no issue. Basically add the ddl into the bin and then add 2 lines into the web.config and away it goes.

https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce

Problems started on our pre-live environment when we've done a self sign certificate to test and redirected all pages to https. Basically the request reduce module stopps outputting files.

Anyone had this issue?

After looking at the dashboard, a comman exception appears which is "The underlying connection was closed - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Still stuck..

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to access your pages using for the host the same name as specified in the certificate for HTTPs.

E.g.: If

- you are working in a domain LAN
- you make tests on your machine ("mymachine")
- for HTTPs, you provided in IIS a certificate issued for "mymachine.mylocaldomain"

then you'll have to access the site using `https://mymachine.mylocaldomain...` (as opposed to `https://mymachine...`!)

(As stated on `https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce/wiki/RequestReduce-is-not-working.-I-don't-see-any-spriting-or-minification.-How-can-I-troubleshoot-this%3F` : 
"If your site is running on HTTPS and you are using a self signed certificate in a dev environment, make sure that certificate has a common name that matches the host name you are using and resides in the trusted certificate authority certificate store. "